# Asp.net calling js from Code Behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I tried to call js function from codebehind like

```
 <if(result == true)
   MyJsFunction();
```

how i can do this?

I tried like

```
string rowTestHide = @" <script type='text/javascript'>function showSuccessMessage(){
                                showNotification({
                                    type : 'success',
                                    message: 'This is a sample success notification'
                                });    
                            }                                
                        </script>";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(null,"rowTest", rowTestHide);
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Please explain _how_ it isn't working, and possibly the relevant `showNotification` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want the function... you just want to run it right away.  Like this:

```
string rowTestHide = @"<script type='text/javascript'>
                                showNotification({
                                    type : 'success',
                                    message: 'This is a sample success notification'
                                });    
                        </script>";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"rowTest", rowTestHide);
```

Comment: When you do a view source do you see the call to `showNotification`?  Maybe you have not defined showNotification?